# Autolayout not working as expected

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

I am trying to build an app with Autolayout. Tried it using storyboard and also programmatically but no luck. Views are not behaving as expected.

This is the output screens. (Targeting iOS7)

[image: This is the output screens.]

Problems: I want green button to be just above the red button with 10px vertical gap. But the red button is getting overlapped on 3.5 inch display, its proper on 4 inch display.

Below is the code I tried.

```
        [self.btnGreen setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [self.viewContainer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.btnGreen attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.viewContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:100.0]];


        [self.viewContainer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.btnGreen attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.viewContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:100.0]];
```

I have Refereed below links:
1) [Apple guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html) 
2) [http://matthewmorey.com/](http://matthewmorey.com/creating-uiviews-programmatically-with-auto-layout/)
3) [Also this one](http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/constant-height-width-constraint-autolayout/)

But not getting desired output.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no need to specify a second item if you're just constraining width or height to a constant. You can do: `[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.btnGreen attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0 constant:width];` instead.

Comment: It looks as though your green button wouldn't even fit in the gap between your red button and the white box above? How would you like the layout to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these constraints shown in Figure : [image]

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But its now working. I am getting the same behavior.

Comment: By doing this the green view gets overlapped with view just above it.

Comment: You should add vertical space constraint from TopView to superView with constant 170 (btnGreenHeight + btnRedHeight + spacings).